# jquery datepicker display in different size in one page

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to make font-size in different of datepicker it's not working.
But if I remove ".mydiv" from `<style>` it's working well.

```
<style>
 .mydiv1 div.ui-datepicker{
  font-size:10px;
}
 .mydiv2 div.ui-datepicker{
  font-size:20px;
}
</style>
<div class="mydiv1">
  <!--{datepickker}-->
</div>
<div class="mydiv2">
  <!--{datepickker}-->
</div>
```

I need to put it inside class "mydiv".
How can I fix this problem.

Comment: If you use `$(".mydiv").datepicker()` then you definitely need to remove the `.mydiv` part in your CSS, otherwise, have a nested `<div>` inside `mydiv` and create the datepicker on that inner div.

Comment: I just update my question. Please help

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to the higher CSS selector specificity of your datepicker. You could try add `html body div.ui-dateicker` as a selector and see if that works.